# Visual Studio 2013 Entity Framework 4.0 Oracle 11.2 and ADO.NET Issue with EDMX file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-4.1, oracle11gr2, edmx-designer

How can I use Entitiy Framework 4.0 within Visual Studio 2013 to connect with Oracle ? I've a working solution for Visual Studio 2010 and Entity Framework 4.1 and Oracle 11.2 version.,But when I'm trying to migrate to Visual Studio 2013, I get ADO.NET oracle.dataaccess.client could not load and/or check machine/app config file error when I open EDMX file. solution is building successfully but I can't open EDMX file due to above error. Is this due to EF6 installation with Visual studio 2013? or VS 2013(EF 6) doesn't work with Oracle 11.2?

Has anyone faced this issue during migration to VS 2013?

are there any known issues as per Oracle thread : https://community.oracle.com/thread/3626219

I followed below links but couldn't succeed in fixing ADO.NET issue

[Deploying and Configuring ODP.NET to work without installation with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721025/deploying-and-configuring-odp-net-to-work-without-installation-with-entity-frame)

[Oracle Instant Client and Entity Framework trouble with configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911948/oracle-instant-client-and-entity-framework-trouble-with-configuration)

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by upgrading to Oracle 12c :

The Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (ODT) is a tightly integrated "Add-in" for Microsoft Visual Studio. ODT is free and supports Visual Studio 2013, VS 2012, and VS 2010. Download ODT 12.1.0.2.0 today!

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html